# Unable to upload file IE9 - Blueimp

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, file-upload, blueimp

I have the following logic to initialize the blueimp uploader

```
                el.fileupload({
                    url: '/media',
                    formData: formData,
                    progressInterval: 300,
                    forceIframeTransport : true, //!window.FormData, temp hack to replicate IE functionality on chrome
                    uploadTemplateId: null,
                    downloadTemplateId: null,
                    singleFileUploads: !scope.config.multiple,
                    change: change,
                    progress: progress,
                    beforeSend: beforeSend,
                    add: add
                });

                el.find('.file-uploader').bind('change', function (e) {
                    el.fileupload('add', {
                        fileInput: $(this) //for ie iframe upload
                    });
                });
```

this is what my HTML (`el` in the code above) looks like:

```
<form id="fileupload">
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file" ng-disabled="disabled" class="file-uploader">
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" ng-if="!config.autoUpload" data-ng-click="submit()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Now when I upload I do not see the file being sent, on investigating `jQuery Iframe Transport Plugin 1.8.3` line 143, the `options.fileInput` has the input element attached to it, but the `files` property on it has a length of 0. As a result of which I see the following as the data being sent to the server:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypfHR2vjNiSu5Y9G8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonString"

{"name":"1439488201502"}
------WebKitFormBoundarypfHR2vjNiSu5Y9G8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarypfHR2vjNiSu5Y9G8--
```

The filename above is blank and the Content-Type is `application/octet-stream` instead of something like `image/jpeg`.

Any help is appreciated.